# Is there an easy way to humanize string in collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given this:

```
  <%= f.collection_select :role_id, @role, :id, :name %>
```

Is there an easy way to humanize or titleize the `:name`, if it's stored as something like `super_admin` ? I tried `humanize(:name)` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to add a method in the model 'role' which returns human name something like

```
class Role< ActiveRecord::Base

    def human_name
      humanize(name)
    end
 end



 <%= f.collection_select :role_id, @role, :id, :human_name%>
```

Comment: if you mean in the method. yep. i just wrote that up using your own code. sorry for not noticing that. any way, am glad it helped.